# How do I overcome the chm2pdf error in the description?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, chm2pdf

The error is:

```
ERR011: Unable to parse HTML element on line 13!
PAGES: 2854
BYTES: 9759142
Something wrong happened when launching htmldoc.
exit value:  256
Check if output exists or if it is good.
Done.
```

Which I received from running `chm2pdf --webpage '/home/brentonhorne/Drugs/CHM/Goodman and gillman.chm'`

I looked in the pdf generated and it had

```
ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC  
$$$$$'--'7;7LLPÿÛC  
"$"'--'7;7LLfÿÀXÎ"ÿÄÿÄ^!1"A2Qaq#BRTbr¡²³Ò36CSst¢±Ñ$%45U´ÁÂÓ¿Dcd£âÃãðEáñ&euòÿÄ?ÓÉ,ãÍé:«+ÜcÃ#ÿJ¦sñÒñ´VÐ£¹æè ÿÒ5Fk»ÁO'ôÚÜC ÷ <
¦Ôð³NÀ·8¡»ºhA2ÉÃ4SLkæ;¤vÈ±¬õ«xJì9þ-ÿf··¢gz«åMìê Çº³²Ü\ËÞ: Ê qê
```

for the first page (book cover). It also failed to render many images and equations, with a lot of text formatting lost (many things that are bold in the original CHM file aren't bold anymore). How do I overcome this problem? I am running 32 bit 12.10 if it helps.

```
CHM2PDF_TEMP_WORK_DIR=tempfile.mkdtemp()
CHM2PDF_TEMP_ORIG_DIR=tempfile.mkdtemp()
```

is located in the /usr/bin/chm2pdf python script.

Comment: Instead of adding a picture of your tmp I would have expected you to check the options`CHM2PDF_TEMP_WORK_DIR` and `CHM2PDF_TEMP_ORIG_DIR` and see if you are using a different directory.

Comment: where do I find this? I should probably tell you now I am a complete and utter noob when it comes to programming, ubuntu, etc. aside from the stuff you pick up from using it for 8 months.

Comment: Read this: http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10275 Bullit point 4 and 5 in the 1st post. Has nothing to do with Ubuntu btw; I use this script mainly with Windows and the same applies there: you need to look in the script with a text editor ;)

Comment: I have added those lies to my question

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal error when the HTML contains other languages (like javascript) or contains formatting errors.

Use `--extract-only` to extract the HTML files from the `CHM`, change the HTML files to something that is valid HTML and then use `--dontextract` to convert the new files into a single PDF (`--extract-only` and `--dontextract` options were created just to overcome these kind of errors).

Some pointers regarding extracting and manipulating a file can be found here:

- http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10275
- http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10965
- http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11078

--
The [first link of these 3](http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10275) show that 2 options `CHM2PDF_TEMP_WORK_DIR` and `CHM2PDF_TEMP_ORIG_DIR` are used to store the temporary files om disc.  From the link:

> This is the only changeable variables in the script. The user can change them to whatever he likes - no other changes are needed. From CHM2PDF_TEMP_WORK_DIR and CHM2PDF_TEMP_ORIG_DIR, the chm2pdf computes its orig and work dirs by adding the basename of the CHM file (without the .chm ending). So if you give it /home/chris/my-file.chm to convert, it will use /tmp/chm2pdf/work/my-file as work directory and /tmp/chm2pdf/orig/my-file as orig directory. It expands the files contained in the CHM file into the orig directory, then copies the ones it needs into its work dir and continues there. The original TEMP_DIR and TEMP_OUT simply did not work out of the box.

Comment: Where will the html files be placed?

Comment: I have checked the directory containing the CHM files and it's not there

Comment: There's heaps of directories inside /tmp and no singular html files are in /tmp

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my /tmp directory to my question.

Comment: I ran a search of the /tmp directory for the keywords "chm2pdf" and I received no hits.